# Calling Java program from Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I want to call Java program from my Ruby script. I am trying to use JRuby, I installed it and I am trying to see how it works.

I started by doing the following simple Java class:

```
package test;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 say();
}

public static void say(){
  System.out.println("oh hi!");  
}
}
```

And the following ruby program,

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'java'
require '/Users/arwa/NetBeansProjects/test/dist/test.jar' 

class Main
 def run
  sayObj = Java::test::test.new
  sayObj.say()
 end
end

app = Main.new
app.run
```

In terminal, when I type

```
jruby test_again.rb
```

I get nothing! I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have issues in both java and ruby.

**java code:** main and 'static' removed

```
package test;

public class Test {

  public void say() {
    System.out.println("oh hi!");
  }

}
```

**ruby code:** you did not respect jruby uppercase when calling java libraries

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'java'
require '/Users/arwa/NetBeansProjects/test/dist/test.jar' 

class Main
 def run
  sayObj = Java::Test::Test.new # NOTE the uppercase
  sayObj.say()
 end
end

app = Main.new
app.run
```